# Why does the interceptor always return "null" (i.e., the initial value) using BehaviorSubject, not the updated value?

Tags: angular, typescript, express, rxjs

I'm building an authentication app using the PEAN stack (i.e., PostgreSQL - ExpressJS - Angular - NodeJS).

I check for user sign-in status as follows:

1. On the backend, check the session cookie to see if the `user` property exists in the `req.session` object.

**server.js**

```
/* ... */

app.post('/api/get-signin-status', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.session.user) {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User logged in' });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User logged out' });
    }
  } catch {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

/* ... */
```

2. Send an HTTP POST request to the `api/get-signin-status` endpoint with optional data and include a cookie in the request.

**auth.service.ts**

```
/* ... */

getSignInStatus(data?: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.authUrl + 'api/get-signin-status', data, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
}

/* ... */
```

3. Intercept any HTTP request and provide an observable `interceptorResponse$` for subscribing to the response of intercepted requests.

**interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  private interceptorResponse$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const signInStatusObserver = {
      next: (x: any) => {
        this.interceptorResponse$.next({ success: true, response: x });
      },

      error: (err: any) => {
        this.interceptorResponse$.next({ success: false, response: err });
      },
    };

    this.authService.getSignInStatus().subscribe(signInStatusObserver);

    return next.handle(httpRequest);
  }

  getInterceptorResponse(): Observable<any> {
    return this.interceptorResponse$.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

4. On the frontend, subscribe to the `interceptorResponse` observable from the `InterceptorService` and log the response to the console.

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { InterceptorService } from '../auth/services/interceptor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  interceptorResponse: any;

  constructor(
    private interceptorService: InterceptorService
  ) {
    this.interceptorService.getInterceptorResponse().subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);

      this.interceptorResponse = response;
      if (response) {
        console.log('Interceptor response success:', response.response);
      } else {
        console.log('Interceptor response is null');
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

#### Problem

According to the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119768/10347145), I should use `BehaviorSubject`. The problem is that in the console, I always get the following:

[image: Screenshot]

But if I console log `next` and `error` like this:

**interceptor.service.ts**

```
/* ... */

const signInStatusObserver = {
  next: (x: any) => {
    console.log(x);
    this.interceptorResponse$.next({ success: true, response: x });
  },

  error: (err: any) => {
    console.log(err.error.message);
    this.interceptorResponse$.next({ success: false, response: err });
  },
};

/* ... */
```

I see the expected `{message: 'User logged in'}` in the console, as shown in the screenshot below. This means that the backend correctly passes sign-in status to the frontend.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Question

**Why does the Angular interceptor always return `null` (i.e., the initial value) using `BehaviorSubject`, not the updated value?**

---

**EDIT 1**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RoutingComponents } from './app-routing.module';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

import { CodeInputModule } from 'angular-code-input';

import { IfSignedOut } from './auth/guards/if-signed-out.guard';
import { IfSignedIn } from './auth/guards/if-signed-in.guard';

import { InterceptorService } from './auth/services/interceptor.service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent, AppComponent, FooterComponent, RoutingComponents],
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, AppRoutingModule, SharedModule, HttpClientModule, MatMenuModule, MatSidenavModule, CodeInputModule],
  providers: [IfSignedOut, IfSignedIn, { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

With the help of @VonC I managed to get the whole thing working as expected. Here's what I did.

1. I removed my initial code in `server.js` because the interceptor will now depend on the `api/get-user` endpoint, not `api/get-signin-status` like before. Consequently, I don't need `app.post('/api/get-signin-status', () => {})` anymore. The reason why I now use the `api/get-user` endpoint is because both did the same thing (i.e., checked the session cookie to see if the `user` property exists in the `req.session` object), which means that only one is enough for my auth app. There's no need to check the session cookie twice.

**server.js**

```
/* ... */

/* Removed */
/*
app.post('/api/get-signin-status', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.session.user) {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User logged in' });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User logged out' });
    }
  } catch {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
*/

/* ... */
```

2. I removed my initial code in `auth.service.ts` and added the code as @VonC suggested.

**auth.service.ts**

```
/* ... */

/* Removed */
/*
getSignInStatus(data?: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.authUrl + 'api/get-signin-status', data, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
}
*/

/* Added */
private signInStatus$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

getSignInStatusObserver(): Observable<any> {
  return this.signInStatus$.asObservable();
}

setSignInStatus(status: any): void {
  this.signInStatus$.next(status);
}

/* ... */
```

3. I removed my initial code in `interceptor.service.ts` and added the code as @VonC suggested. *Note: I changed the endpoint from `api/get-signin-status` to `api/get-user`.*

**interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && httpRequest.url.endsWith('api/get-user')) {
          this.authService.setSignInStatus({ success: true, response: event.body });
        }
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (httpRequest.url.endsWith('api/get-user')) {
          this.authService.setSignInStatus({ success: false, response: err });
        }
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

4. I removed my initial code in `header.component.ts` and added the code as @VonC suggested.

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth/services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  signInStatus: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, public publicAuthService: AuthService, private signOutRouter: Router, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    this.authService.getSignInStatusObserver().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.signInStatus = response;
      if (response) {
        console.log('Sign in status success:', response.response);
      } else {
        console.log('Sign in status is null');
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Now I can finally show elements in `header.component.html` depending on sign-in status coming from the backend as follows:

**header.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="signInStatus">Show this element if the user is signed in</div>
<div *ngIf="!signInStatus">Show this element if the user is signed out</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve some issue in general, or you want BehaviorSubject solution only?

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz sample?

Comment: @Sergey What could be an alternative solution? I read that `BehaviorSubject` is the best option. Hm, I will try.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in general you want to implement a basic auth for requests, right? I mean that it doesn't have anything extraordinary to it.

Comment: Any chance you end up with two instances of the service? One gets injected in the header component and another one used as an interceptor? That would explain why you don't get notifications on observable updates.

Comment: Can you show you app.compoennt and app.module?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof See the edit. My `app.component.ts` is empty.

Comment: @Sergey Why would two instances cause the problem?

Comment: Because as I explained you may be observing the changes on one, while updates receives the other. It's like opening a room, but checking the wrong door for being open. In another building.

Comment: To be more precise, you should be asking not why the Interceptor has `null`, but why it doesn't get updated. `BehaviorSubject` gives you an initial value. It's being subscribed to before any requests are made. And this is evident from the logs. What's weird is that your HeaderComponent doesn't receive any updates after the requests are made.

Comment: Without being able to play around the issue myself I can only guess that it happens because you subscribe to one instance and another instance receives the actual updates. That would explain this behavior.

Comment: Lastly, as a last resort you could try removing `dist` and `.angular` folders and running the browser in an incognito mode. Sometimes cache manages to surprise

Comment: @Sergey With the help of VonC (see his answer below), I managed to solve the problem. Thanks for the time and attention you gave to my question. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`interceptor response is null`" might be expected: the way you are using the [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) in your interceptor may be causing this issue.

The purpose of an interceptor is to intercept HTTP requests and do something with those requests or responses.
(See for instance "**[Intro to Angular Http Interceptors](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/intro-to-angular-http-interceptors)**" from **[Cory Rylan](https://github.com/coryrylan)**)

But in your interceptor, you are creating a *new* HTTP request by calling `this.authService.getSignInStatus().subscribe(signInStatusObserver);` instead of intercepting an existing one. That means the response to this request might not be available immediately when your component subscribes to `getInterceptorResponse()`.
... hence possibly the null interceptor response.

---

As an example, you could use an interceptor to check the user's authentication status:

```js
// interceptor.service.ts

import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && httpRequest.url.endsWith('/api/get-signin-status')) {
          this.authService.setSignInStatus({ success: true, response: event.body });
        }
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (httpRequest.url.endsWith('/api/get-signin-status')) {
          this.authService.setSignInStatus({ success: false, response: err });
        }
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

In this updated version, we are subscribing to the `handle` method of `next`, which returns an [`Observable`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular) of the HTTP response. It uses the `tap` operator to do something with the successful responses and the `catchError` operator to handle errors.

I am assuming `setSignInStatus` is a method in your `AuthService` that updates the sign-in status stored in a `BehaviorSubject`.
I am also checking if the request URL ends with '`/api/get-signin-status`' to make sure we are only setting the sign-in status for that specific request.

That means you might implement this user's authentication status with:

```js
// auth.service.ts

private signInStatus$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

getSignInStatusObserver(): Observable<any> {
  return this.signInStatus$.asObservable();
}

setSignInStatus(status: any): void {
  this.signInStatus$.next(status);
}
```

You would need to update your `header.component.ts` to use `authService` instead of `interceptorService`:

```js
// header.component.ts

constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  this.authService.getSignInStatusObserver().subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(response);

    this.interceptorResponse = response;
    if (response) {
      console.log('Interceptor response success:', response.response);
    } else {
      console.log('Interceptor response is null');
    }
  });
}
```

---

Finally, in your component, you would then subscribe to `getSignInStatusObserver` instead of `getInterceptorResponse`.

That ensures that the sign-in status is updated every time an HTTP response is received from '`/api/get-signin-status`' and that components can subscribe to the status updates.

The subscription in your component would look like:

```js
// header.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  signInStatus: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.getSignInStatusObserver().subscribe((response: any) => {
      // That block of code will run every time the signInStatus updates
      console.log(response);

      this.signInStatus = response;
      if (response) {
        console.log('Sign in status success:', response.response);
      } else {
        console.log('Sign in status is null');
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

In the constructor of `HeaderComponent`, we are injecting `AuthService` instead of `InterceptorService`. We are subscribing to `getSignInStatusObserver()`, which is a method in `AuthService` that returns an `Observable` of the sign-in status. When the sign-in status is updated, the subscribed function will be called with the new status as the argument.

We are storing the sign-in status in the `signInStatus` property and logging it to the console. We are also logging a success message if the response exists and a message indicating the sign-in status is null otherwise. That mirrors the behavior of your original code.

Comment: I spent some time implementing your suggestion, and it looks very promising. I correctly get sign-in status, but because I changed the endpoint from `api/get-signin-status` to `api/get-user`, I will continue tomorrow, and if everything works fine, I will of course accept your answer and give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that Angular creates multiple instances of your interceptorService. One actually used as an interceptor and one is injected into your components/services.

I vaguely remember having the same problem. Back then, I solved it like this:

```
class Interceptor{
    constructor(private final service: SharedDataService){}
}

class Component{
    constructor(private final service: SharedDataService){}
}
```

Both the component and interceptor use another service to share data.

**EDIT**

A quick search actually confirms this. See [Interceptor create two instances of singleton service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268285/interceptor-create-two-instances-of-singleton-service)

Comment: With the help of VonC (see his answer above), I managed to solve the problem. Thanks for the time and attention you gave to my question. I appreciate it very much.